# Dynamically load background image in template

Tags: html, css, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a list object as follows:

```
<div role="list" class="w-clearfix w-dyn-items w-row">
    {% if latest_post_list %}
    {% for post in latest_post_list %}
    {% if post.is_published %}
    <div role="listitem" class="blog-thumbnail w-dyn-item w-col w-col-4">
        <a href="/{{ post.id }}" data-w-id="46150442-4efa-9d36-3a4c-20d527e7a6bc" class="thumbnail-wrapper w-inline-block">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <div style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0)" class="thumbnail-image"></div>
            <div class="category-tag">{{ post.category }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail-text">
            <div class="blog-title">{{ post.title}}</div>
            <div class="preview-text">{{ post.body}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-details w-clearfix"><img src="" alt="" class="author-img">
            <div class="author-title">{{ post.author }}</div>
            <div class="thumbnail-date">{{ post.pub_date }}</div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}


    </div>
    <div class="w-dyn-empty">
        <p>No items found.</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

The background image is set in stylesheet:

```
  background-image: url('https://foo.bar.net/img/background-image.svg');
```

An image is added to the category model using an Imagefield.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I would like to have the background image set to be the uploaded category image and default to the current URL if null but can not get the image variable working in the template i.e

`background-image: url('../images/{{ category.image}}');`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the `category`'s image to a background like this:

`<div style="background-image: url({{ category.image.url }});"></div>`

Comment: Also, don't mix your media and static files with your ```upload_to='static/'```. Static are supposed to be things that aren't changing, like your css and js, not things from model instances.

Comment: The image variable is getting stripped when the page renders, could I be missing something here?
```style="background-image: url();"```

Comment: I modifed the element to the following which at least shows the path but still doesn't render the image, it's at lease a step in the right direction ```<div style="background: url('{{ post.category.image.url  }}') 10% 10% no-repeat;"></div>```

Comment: Remove the extra ' ' in your ```url``` template tag call. see mine: ```url({{ category.image.url }})```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I've modified the list object as follows which achieves the intended result:

```
          <div role="list" class="w-clearfix w-dyn-items w-row">
            {% if latest_post_list %}
            {% for post in latest_post_list %}
            {% if post.is_published %}
            <div role="listitem" class="blog-thumbnail w-dyn-item w-col w-col-4">
              <a href="/{{ post.id }}" data-w-id="46150442-4efa-9d36-3a4c-20d527e7a6bc" class="thumbnail-wrapper w-inline-block">
                <div class="image-wrapper">
                  <img src="{{ post.category.image.url  }}" loading="lazy" srcset="{{ post.category.image.url  }}"   alt="" class="thumbnail-image">
                  <div class="category-tag">{{ post.category }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumbnail-text">
                  <div class="blog-title">{{ post.title}}</div>
                  <div class="preview-text">{{ post.body}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="thumb-details w-clearfix"><img src="" alt="" class="author-img">
                  <div class="author-title">{{ post.author }}</div>
                  <div class="thumbnail-date">{{ post.pub_date }}</div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
              {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
              {% else %}


          </div>
          <div class="w-dyn-empty">
            <p>No items found.</p>
          </div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
```